# NS2 program TCP over noisy channel error

Tags: ns2

## Set error model on link n2 to n3

set loss_module [new ErrorMode]
$loss_module set rate_ 0.1

## Create the Simulator instance

set ns [new Simulator]
$ns color Red
$ns color Blue

## Open NAM trace file

$set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

## Open the Trace file

set tf [open out.tr w]
set windowVsTime2 [open WindowVsTimeNReno w]
$ns trace-all $tf

## Define a 'finish' procedure

proc finish {} {
    global ns nf tf 
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    cose $tf
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}

## Create four nodes

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]

$ns at 0.1 "n1 label \"CBR\"" 
$ns at 1.0 "n0 label \"FTP\""

## Create links between the nodes

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 2Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 2Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns simplex-link $n2 $n3 0.07Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns simplex-link $n3 $n2 0.07Mb 20ms Droptail

## Set queue size for link n2-n3 to 10

$ns queue-limit $n2 $n3 10

## Moniter the queue for link n2-n3 for NAM

$ns simplex-link op $n2 $n3 queuePos 0.5

## Set error model on link n3 to n2

set loss_module [new ErrorModel]
$loss_module set rate_ 0.2
$loss_module ranvar [new RandomVariable/Uniform]
$loss_module drop-target [new Agent/Null]
$ns lossmodel $loss_module $n2 $n3

## detach tcp and sink agent

$ns at 624.5 "$ns detach-agent $n0 $tcp ; $ns detach-agent $n3 $sink"

$ns at 625.0 "finish"
$ns run

---

The error I'm getting after running the above code is as follows:

invalid command name

"ErrorMode"

while executing

"ErrorMode create _o3 "

invoked from within

"catch "$className create $o $args" msg"

invoked from within

"if [catch "$className create $o $args" msg] {

if [string match "__FAILED_SHADOW_OBJECT_" $msg] {

delete $o

return ""

}

global errorInfo

error "class $..."

```
(procedure "new" line 3)

invoked from within
```

"new ErrorMode"

```
invoked from within
```

"set loss_module [new ErrorMode]"

```
(file "u.tcl" line 2)
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question about Ubuntu. Are you sure it shouldn't be Error**Model** (rather than ErrorMode)?

Comment: @steeldriver I have  tried this (the solution given) but this doesn't seems to be working.